# Alternative way for dynamic inbound endpoint for Mule 3

Tags: mule

I am working on migrating my Mule 2 project to Mule 3. However, since Mule 3.3 stop supporting dynamic inbound endpoint, I need to find an alternative way to rewrite my inbound endpoint.

Basically, I want to make http call to get some data from specific websites by using current system time as the query parameter. My codes in mule-config.xml is like the following

```
<flow name="RetrieveNewsService">
    <http:inbound-endpoint host="www.awebsite.com" port="80" path="datacenter/someData.asp?category=1&amp;date=[function:dateStamp:MMddyyyy]" connector-ref="RetrieveNewsPollingHttpConnector" exchange-pattern="one-way" />
    //doing some process
</flow>
```

I feed current time for "path" part, and it works perfect in Mule 2, but get the exception mentioning about dynamic inbound endpoint is not supported anymore.

Anyone has any idea how to rewrite the dynamic path for inbound endpoint and what is the purpose they decide to stop this feature? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `poll` on an HTTP `outbound-endpoint` as demonstrated here:

```
<flow name="RetrieveNewsService">
  <poll frequency="10000">
    <http:outbound-endpoint method="GET" host="localhost"
        port="8082" path="test?dtm=#[server.dateTime.format('MMddyyyy')]"
        exchange-pattern="request-response" />
  </poll>

  //doing some process
</flow>
```

PS. No idea why.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response...But I have come up some cases that might not be fixed based on what you are suggesting to do. I have updated those cases on my original post. Thank you!

Comment: Pretty bad practice to alter an existing question, especially when you've received a valid answer to it. To answer your extra questions: 1) it doesn't change anything. 2) Of course. BTW consider using the `invoke` message processor instead of `method-entry-point-resolver` + `spring-object`, as it does the same thing but simpler.

Comment: Sorry David I just came up more questions based on your answers and I thought it is ok to append them on my existing question. Next time I will make another post. Sorry about that and thanks for your help!